# Why can i only choose one value in this form?

Tags: php, forms

I'm using this code to generate questions form database, it works! But i can only answer 1 question and save to database, why? If I try to answer multiple questions, the radio button value just moves around?

```
$question_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_id']);
foreach ($_POST['answer_value'] as $question_id => $answer_id);

 $sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_value)
  VALUES ('$question_id', '$answer_value')"; 

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 echo 'answer saved';
 mysqli_close($con);


 // generate all quetions
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo '<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
                    Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
                    Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
                    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>';
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    echo '  
        <tr>
                <td>'.$body.'</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="2"></td><br>

         </tr>';

    }
     echo'<input type="submit"></form>
                        <br/>';
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Each radio button group needs a distinct name attribute. All of yours are sharing `name="answer_value"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a separate radio group for each question. Use different `name`s each time you go around the loop.

You can store your question id there instead of in a hidden input.

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_value[<?php echo $question_id; ?>]" value="1">
```

When this gets submitted back to the server, you will find that `$_POST['answer_value'][]` is an associative array with the question ids being the keys.

Comment: When adding:
     <td><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id;']"  value="1"></td>
My submit button is disappearing, I'm I interrupting the echo statement for the form?

Comment: You've used a `;` when you need a `.`

Comment: I really don't get what would like to be the correct POST for the question_id: $answer_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['answer_value'][]);

 $sql="INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer_value)
 VALUES ('$question_id', '$answer_value')";

Comment: `foreach $_POST['answer_value'] as $question_id => $answer_id` but 
**Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: thx for the info abot sql injections. But i get an syntax error with
     foreach $_POST['answer_value'] as $question_id => $answer_id

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss the `()` off around it. See http://php.net/foreach for the proper syntax.

Comment: Thx for your reply, i really appreciate your help. I have edited my code above. When i try your solution i'm only saving the total count of questions answered in question_id in database? How Come?

Comment: You need to put the stuff you want to do for each item in the array *in a block following the `foreach` statement*.

Answer (score 0):

If different radiobuttons have the same name, you can only choose one of them (you're grouping them). **This is how it is mean to work**, you can change to *checkbox* input instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer_value[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answer_value[]" value="2" />
```

Then you can check `$_POST['answer_value']` to know ho many were checked and which value they had.

Comment: That would allow multiple answers per question, which isn't the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Make each answer has the same name per question because all radio boxes with the same name are linked in html and will work as one big radiobutton group.
Use a question-ID tosolve that:

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_value_'.$row["question_id"].'" value="1">
```

Comment: Using a checkbox would allow multiple answers per question. That isn't the goal.

Comment: Okok, my bad, srry. I made a little misstake understanding what the author wants. There are multiple questions, I thought he was upset about multiple answer possibilities not workin~.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are looping through the $_POST['answer_value'] but only grabbing the last value.

Try the following code instead:

```
    foreach ($_POST['answer_value'] as $question_id => $answer_id) {
      var_dump($question_id);
    }
```

Inside the brackets ({}), you may do your database insertion.
However, it might be a better idea to save the question and answers to a string that you'll later use in the mysql_query, to avoid unnecessary calls to the database.